# JSF richfaces popup before method

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces, crud

Want to want to do is:
On my datatable, the last column has a view, edit and delete. the View has the following method to get the row data:

```
public String prepareView() {
    current = (TimeLoggingDetail) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
    return "View";
}
```

When view is clicked it redirects me to a page where I can view the selected values.
I want to change that into showing the values in a popup and not get redirected to a page where its displayed.

So I have tried the following:

```
<a4j:commandLink id="myLink" value="Action" actionListener="#{timeLoggingDetailController.prepareView}" rendered="#{item.timeLoggingId eq AdminTimeLogging.filteredId}" styleClass="auto-style5">
    <rich:componentControl event="complete" target="popup" operation="show"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

If I click the button the popup does not show, when I remove the `event="complete"` the popup does show but with no values. If I remove the popup code completely, click on view and then add the popup code again it displays but only the old value I selected without popup code, The values that's in memory.

I have also tried:

```
<a4j:commandLink id="myBut" action="#{timeLoggingDetailController.prepareView}" execute="@this" value="Test" styleClass="auto-style5" render="popup" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.show()">
                            </a4j:commandLink>
```

It also does not open the popup, I have tried using `#{rich:component('popup')}.show()` in numerous ways but it does not open, Should I change the method `prepareView` to return something specific? should I do a condition to display the popup with those values? it seems like the popup opens before the method finishes. the `<a4j:commandLink/>` is within the code:

```
<h:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
   </f:facet>
   <a4j:commandLink id="myBut" action="#{timeLoggingDetailController.prepareView}" execute="@this" value="Test" styleClass="auto-style5" render="popup" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.show()">
   </a4j:commandLink>
<h:column/>
```

My popup Panel:

```
<h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <a4j:commandLink id="myBut" action="#{timeLoggingDetailController.prepareView}" execute="@this" value="Test" styleClass="auto-style5" render="popup" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.show()">
                        </a4j:commandLink>
                        <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true" autosized="true" resizeable="false" domElementAttachment="form">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="TEST" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="controls">
                                <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide();
                                        return false;">
                                    Close
                                </h:outputLink>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_date}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.date}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_date}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                                </h:outputText>
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_description}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.description}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_description}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_normalHours}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.normalHours}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_normalHours}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_overtimeHours}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.overtimeHours}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_overtimeHours}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_doubleTimeHours}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.doubleTimeHours}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_doubleTimeHours}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_approvalLevelsId}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.approvalLevelsId}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_approvalLevelsId}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>value="#{approvalLevelsController.selected.description}" title="#{bundle.ViewApprovalLevelsTitle_description}"/>

                            <br />
                            <h:panelGrid  class="auto-style4">
                                <h:commandLink   action="#{timeLoggingDetailController.update}" value="#{bundle.EditTimeLoggingDetailSaveLink}" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide();" styleClass="linkbutton"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </rich:popupPanel>
                    </h:column>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to tell the whole story: `#{rich:component('popup')}.show()` doesn't work probably because it can't find the popup (any panels/nesting around the component?). `complete` (not to be confused with `oncomplete` *js* callback) is not be a valid event for `<a4j:commandLink/>`

Comment: updated the code where the popup is